# как пользоваться <pcre.h>?

Tags: linux, c

Читаю я nginx исходники и дошел до функции ngx_regex_init (), а там такое

```
pcre_malloc = ngx_regex_malloc;
pcre_free = ngx_regex_free;
```

Открыл руководство man, а там написано что pcre это perl совместимые регулярные выражения. А как ими пользоваться (pcre)? Там столько функций, что не понятно что к чему. Также не понятно, почему в malloc указал это

```
static ngx_inline void
ngx_regex_malloc_init(ngx_pool_t *pool)
{
    ngx_pcre_pool = pool;
}
```

Comment: Посмотреть [демо](https://github.com/vmg/pcre/blob/master/pcredemo.c) например, и поизучать [оригинальный сайт](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/) pcre

Comment: "Также не понятно, почему в malloc указал это" - о ком здесь идет речь? **Кто** "указал это"?

Comment: ну написал же что nginx. То есть указал автор nginx.

Comment: А чего там непонятного, указатель на структуру, присваивается глобальной переменной. Вам это фрагмент ничего не даст, надо смотреть модель работы с памятью.